# Codeigniter DataGrid Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, datagrid

So, I am building myself a simple(ish) datagrid class for my CodeIgniter app.

What I am wondering is, I have some columns that I would like to "format" in that I mean, some may contain only a `1` or a `0`, yet I want to turn them into a `Yes` or `No` respectively.

How can I do this?  In other words, I want to be able to pass in another parameter..something like:

`$this->_columnCallBack` pass it an array like `array(column_number=>'NameOfCallBackFunction')`

I am assuming that I would do it somewhat like I did the `_columnclass`, where I pass in the column number, and the class as an array... but I don't know how I would get the function to fire off to do the replacement...

## Code

```
class O7thDG {
    
    public function __construct($params){
        $this->_table = $params['table'];
        $this->_pk = $params['pk'];
        $this->_fields = (isset($params['fields'])) ? $params['fields'] : null;
        $this->_where = (isset($params['where'])) ? $params['where'] : null;
        $this->_order = (isset($params['order'])) ? $params['order'] : null;
        $this->_extras = (isset($params['extras'])) ? $params['extras'] : null;
        $this->_add = (isset($params['add'])) ? $params['add'] : FALSE;
        $this->_edit = (isset($params['edit'])) ? $params['edit'] : FALSE;
        $this->_delete = (isset($params['delete'])) ? $params['delete'] : FALSE;
        $this->_editlink = (isset($params['editlink'])) ? $params['editlink'] : null;
        $this->_deletelink = (isset($params['deletelink'])) ? $params['deletelink'] : null;
        $this->_editlinkextras = (isset($params['editlinkextras'])) ? $params['editlinkextras'] : null;
        $this->_deletelinkextras = (isset($params['deletelinkextras'])) ? $params['deletelinkextras'] : null;
        $this->_tableid = (isset($params['tableid'])) ? $params['tableid'] : null;
        $this->_tableclass = (isset($params['tableclass'])) ? $params['tableclass'] : null;
        $this->_columnclass = (isset($params['columnclass'])) ? $params['columnclass'] : null;
        $this->_includeheader = (isset($params['includeheader'])) ? $params['includeheader'] : TRUE;
        $this->_allowpaging = (isset($params['allowpaging'])) ? $params['allowpaging'] : FALSE;
        $this->_sorting = (isset($params['sorting'])) ? $params['sorting'] : null;
        $this->_columncallback = (isset($params['columncallback'])) ? $params['columncallback'] : null;
    }
    
    public function BuildIt($responsive = TRUE){
        $_ci =& get_instance();
        $_ci->load->database();
        $_ci->load->library('table');
        $_ci->load->library('TKCommon', null, 'comm');
        $fldlist = $this->_buildSelectFieldList();
        $_ci->db->select($fldlist);
        $cols = $this->_buildColumnFieldList();
        $ret = '';
        if($this->_where != null){
            // build the where
            
        }
        if($this->_order != null){
            // build the order
            
        }
        if($this->_extras != null){
            // build the extras
            
        }           
        // Query the specified table
        $qry = $_ci->db->get($this->_table);
        if($cols == null){
            $cols = $_ci->db->list_fields($this->_table);
            $fldlist = $cols;
        }else{
            $fldlist = explode(', ', $fldlist);
        }
        if($qry){
            // throw the results into an associative array
            $rs = $qry->result_array();
            if($rs){
                $rCt = count($rs);
                $cCt = $qry->num_fields();
                // add our responsive wrapper
                if($responsive){
                    $ret .= '<div class="table-responsive">';
                }
                // fire up our table
                $tid = '';
                $tc = '';
                if($this->_tableid != null){$tid = ' id="' .$this->_tableid . '"';}
                if($this->_tableclass != null){$tc = ' class="' .$this->_tableclass . '"';}
                $_ci->table->set_template(array('table_open'=>'<table' . $tid . $tc . '>'));
                // build our header row, but only if we need to
                if($this->_includeheader && $cCt > 0){
                    // see if we need to include the admin column
                    if($this->_edit || $this->_delete){
                        $_ci->table->set_heading(array_merge($cols, array('Admin')));
                    }else{
                        $_ci->table->set_heading($cols);
                    }
                }
                // build each records row
                for($r = 0; $r < $rCt; ++$r){
                    $ca = array();
                    for($c = 0; $c < $cCt; ++$c){
                        if(($this->_columnclass != null) && ($c == key($this->_columnclass))){
                            // figure out which column needs the class, and what class needs to be applied
                            $ca[] = $this->_columnCallback($c, array('data'=>$rs[$r][$fldlist[$c]], 'class'=>$this->_columnclass[key($this->_columnclass)]));
                        }else{
                            $ca[] = $this->_columnCallback($c, $rs[$r][$fldlist[$c]]);  
                        }
                    }
                    // see if we need to include the admin column
                    if(($this->_edit || $this->_delete) && ($this->_editlink != null || $this->_deletelink != null)){
                        $txt = '';
                        if($this->_edit &&($this->_editlink != null)){
                            $txt .= '<a href="' . $this->_editlink . '?id=' . $rs[$r][$this->_pk] . '"><span class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                        }
                        if($this->_delete &&($this->_deletelink != null)){
                            $txt .= '<a href="' . $this->_deletelink . '?id=' . $rs[$r][$this->_pk] . '"><span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></span></a>';
                        }
                        if(($this->_columnclass != null) && ($cCt == key($this->_columnclass))){
                            $ca[] = array('data'=>$txt, 'class'=>$this->_columnclass[key($this->_columnclass)]);
                        }else{
                            $ca[] = $txt;
                        }
                    }
                    $_ci->table->add_row($ca);
                }                   
                $ret .= $_ci->table->generate();
                // close our responsive wrapper
                if($responsive){
                    $ret .= '</div>';
                }
            }else{
                $ret .= $_ci->comm->ErrorBox('There was an issue running the query, please make sure at least your primary key, and table are correct.');
            }
        }else{
            $ret .= $_ci->comm->ErrorBox('There was an issue running the query, please make sure at least your primary key, and table are correct.');
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    
    // build our select's field list
    private function _buildSelectFieldList(){
        if($this->_fields == null){
            return '*'; 
        }else{
            $flds = array_map(function($item){return $item['field'];}, $this->_fields);
            return implode(', ', $flds);
        }
    }
    
    // build our tables column list
    private function _buildColumnFieldList(){
        if($this->_fields == null){
            return null;
        }else{
            return array_map(function($item){return $item['label'];}, $this->_fields);
        }
    }
    
    private function _columnCallback($col, $val){
        if($this->_columncallback != null){
            if($col == key($this->_columncallback))
                return $this->_columncallback[key($this->_columncallback)]($val);
        }else{
            return $val;
        }
    }
            
}
```

and my external function that I may want to use is simply:

```
// Format boolean value to Yes or No
public function YesNo($val){
    return ((bool)$val) ? 'Yes' : 'No' ;    
}
```

CI Documentation for the table class has `$this->table->function`, however, the function(s) passed applies to the entire table

Comment: Hi I don't get it at all, this "callback" will be implemented by you to be used by your class ? or you want that someone else using your class (you or another dev) will send the callback name as a custom function, sorry If didn't explain very well.

Comment: do you want to use your YesNo function as: $O7thDG->YesNo, passing the function name (YesNo) to some function in your class O7thDG like someCallbackForReplaceValues("YesNo",$parameter=null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using and/or anonymous functions:

http://docs.php.net/manual/es/function.func-get-args.php

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

**Update 2 "reloaded"**

You could also check grocery crud, it's CI library and do some interesting things that can be useful for you project:

http://www.grocerycrud.com/

**Grocery crud** uses  [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) from PHP and **allows you to use any function declaread in your controller**, if this is what you need then it's just matter of time and check grocery crud code.

In the library a protected property is declared for each callback for example **(line #3386 v1.4.1)**:

```
/* Callbacks */
protected $callback_before_insert = null;
```

So you/me/any can set the callback function in case is needed, then check for any callback setted doing something like **(line #878 GroceryCrud 1.4.1)**:

```
if($this->callback_before_insert !== null)
{
    $callback_return = call_user_func($this->callback_before_insert, $post_data);

        if(!empty($callback_return) && is_array($callback_return))
            $post_data = $callback_return;
       elseif($callback_return === false)
            return false;
}
```

Of course there's a method to set the callback (line #4518 from v1.4.1):

```
public function callback_before_insert($callback = null)
{
    $this->callback_before_insert = $callback;
    return $this;
}
```

And the user/dev set the callback doing:

```
$crud->callback_before_insert(array($this,'my_callback'));
```

And/Or this technique allows you use something like:

```
$this->load->model('Customers');
$crud->callback_before_insert(array($this->Customers,'getCustomersCallback'));
```

even if you're usign php 5.3 or greater you can use an anonymous method:

```
$crud->callback_before_insert(function($post_array){
    $post_array['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    return $post_array;
});
```

More info: http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/tutorial_using_callbacks

**About Grocery Crud:**

Author: [John Skoumbourdis](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JohnSkoumbourdis/posts) ([more about author/library](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Grocery-CRUD/226957574012339))

Web: [GroceryCrud](http://www.grocerycrud.com)

License: released with dual licensing, using the GPL v3 and the MIT license.

**Update 3**
Update I've read more carefully your question, thinking functions varible can work for you:

http://php.net/manual/es/functions.variable-functions.php

See the first and second samples here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Still don't know if they will work "outside" your class, but it could.

Comment: Unfortunately they do not work outside the class...  so at this point I am wondering if I might be better off taking a more ORM approach.  With which I can then simply attach another property to my mapping, and format it that way.

Answer (score 0):

These functions will work as you want to, but you need to rewrite a bit for your needs.

```
function callback1($array, $row_id, $function)
{
    if(function_exists($function))
        return $function($array[$row_id]);
    else
        return 0;
}

function YesNo($val) 
{
    return intval($val) ? 'Yes' : 'No' ;    
}

#example of array and usage of script.
$array = array('id' => '0', 'id2' => '1');
$ok = callback1($array, 'id2', 'YesNo');
```

Comment: doesn't quite work.  The function is loaded in from another class... I think that is what is tripping it up.  In fact, it does not work even if the YesNo function resides inside the O7thDG class.  I get ye-ol `undefined function` error

Comment: The problem is, none of these potential callback functions should reside in the same class as this... kind of the whole point of having a callback...   I updated my code int he question to match closer to the class

Comment: it does not work inside my class... see a few comments ago.  I get the same issue when the function resides in the class

Answer (score 0):

Make filters array

```
$this->filters = ['column_name' => 'function_name', 'column_name2' => 'otherFunction'];
```

Then you just apply the filter to the data

```
if ( array_key_exists($column_name, $this->filters) ) {
   // Add row that contains filtered data
   $row_data = $this->filters[$column_name]($column_val);
}else{
   $row_data = $column_val;
}
```

If your functions aren't available globally (not in a helper or built-in php), you'll have to use something like this:

```
call_user_func(array($this, $this->filters[$column_name]), $column_val);

OR

$this->{$this->filters[$column_name]}($column_val);
```

This would run a function from inside the library O7...